# Drupal Console With DDEV

Tags: drupal, ddev, drupal-console

I want to install drupal console with composer from **DDEV** (https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

No problem to install Drush with DDEV

**DDEV cannot be Root.**

> Not populating custom commands or hostadditions because running with root privileges
> ddev is not designed to be run with root privileges, please run as normal user and without sudo

My command :

`ddev composer update drupal/console --with-dependencies`

But the response is :

Dependency "composer/installers" is also a root requirement, but is not
explicitly allowed. Ignoring.

Dependency "composer/installers" is also a root requirement, but is not
explicitly allowed. Ignoring.

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should
avoid using it.

Use psr/container instead.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
Use roave/better-reflection instead.

Generating autoload files
44 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

---

For Drush I use:

`ddev drush args`

I would like to do

`ddev drupal args`

Sorry for my language.

Thanks!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as far as I can tell Drupal Console is unmaintained and has been uninstallable or unreliable for more than a year, so the binary was removed from ddev.

However, that doesn't keep you from installing it in your project, `ddev composer require drupal/console`. But any errors that you get are a result of problems with Drupal Console, and don't have to do with ddev.

Now, if you'd like a custom command for Drupal Console, you can create one. Just copy ~/.ddev/commands/web/drush to ~/.ddev/commands/web/drupal and edit as you see fit. This is an example of a custom command. There are other examples in ~/.ddev/commands/web. Read about [custom commands in the docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/custom-commands/).